# warning unmappable character for encoding utf8 while running ant build in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, string

In below code I am trying to replace minus(–) with hyphen(-).

Str="1020 – 1030";

Str = str.replaceAll("–", "-");

When I run this code in eclipse console it worked fine but while running build I am sew below warning and minus is not replaced.

warning: unmappable character for encoding utf8

Please let me know is there any other way to replace minus.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked which charset is used to encode your java file?

Comment: Hi Atao, How can I check that?

Comment: Under your editor, check the preferences/setup. By the way, what is your OS?

Comment: Under Eclipse: select the file, then Properties > Resources, then check the box "Text file encoding"